# How to create a textbox/shapes inside a textbox in HTML

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, grails

i would like to create a input textbox where inside of it has a shapes or whatever.

[Click here for my desired output. :)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5W7fN.jpg)

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `:after` & `:before` because **`:before` and `:after` render inside a container and `<input>` cannot contain other elements**.

The best you can do is -

- create a `<span>` tag which will be your shape
- create a container wrapping both the input & the `<span>` next to it.
- position the `<span>` accordingly inside the input using `position: absolute;`.

  I have created a pen [Shown here](http://codepen.io/PleaseBugMeNot/pen/GjkGPg)

HTML

```
<div class="container">
  <input type="text" />
  <span></span>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.container { display: inline; position: relative;}
input { width: 400px; }
span {
  background: green;
  position: absolute;
  right: 5px;
  top: 4px;
  width: 20px;
  height: 10px;
}
```